# Investigate whether the given transformation is a monomorphism / epimorphism. Find image and kernel

Tags: linear-algebra, monomorphisms

I have serious doubts - I will be very grateful if someone will help me here

Investigate whether the given transformation is a monomorphism / epimorphism. Find its image and kernel.
$$ F \in L(\mathbb R[x]_3,\mathbb R[x]_3), F(p)(t) = p(t+1) - p(t)  $$

### My try

Okay, let 
$$ p(t) = ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d $$
then 
$$F(p)(t) = ... = 3ax^2 + 3ax + 2bx + 3 = x^2(3a)+x(3a+2b) +3 = a(3x^2+3x) + b(2x) + 3 $$
Is it monomorphism?
let $m_0 = 0  \wedge  m_1 = 3a  \wedge m_2 = 3a+b  \wedge m_3 = 3$

so $a = \frac{m_1}{3} \wedge b = \frac{m_2-m_1}{2} $ 
so $a$ and $b$  are determined unambiguously so it is monomorphism

 It is not epimorphism because $ x^3 \in\mathbb R[x]_3 $ but I can't get $x^3$ in use of $F$ 
$\ker F = \left\{ 0 \right\} $ because of part $ 3 $ it will be never polynomial zero

If it comes to image, we checked that:
$$F(p)(t) = ... = a(3x^2+3x) + b(2x) + 3 $$
so $ im(F) = span(3x^2+3,2x,3) $ 
Moreover this system is lineary independent so $rank(F) = 3$

Have I done this correctly? Or there is something to fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a contradiction in your solution: if the map is injective it must also be surjective, because it is a linear map of a finite dimensional vector space to itself.

It's much easier with matrices. If you consider the standard basis $\{p_0=1,p_1=t,p_2=t^2,p_3=t^3\}$, then you see that
$$
F(p_0)=0,\quad
F(p_1)=1,\quad
F(p_2)=2t+1\quad
F(p_3)=3t^2+3t+1
$$
and therefore the matrix of $F$ is
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 2 & 3 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 3 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}

What's the rank of this matrix?

---

Where did you go wrong? The image of $p(t)=at^3+bt^2+ct+d$ is
\begin{align}
p(t+1)-p(t)
&=at^3+3at^2+3at+a+bt^2+2bt+b+ct+d-at^3-bt^2-ct-d\\
&=3at^2+(3a+2b)t+(a+b+c)
\end{align}
which is zero when
\begin{cases}
3a=0\\
3a+2b=0\\
a+b+c=0
\end{cases}
so when $a=b=c=0$. But $d$ can be anything. Thus the nullity is $1$ and the rank is $3$.

Comment: rank of this matrix is 3. Can you point me which poin twhere exactly do I have the mistake?

Comment: @VirtualUser The rank is $3$.

Comment: Yes, stupid mistake, I had on mind $3$. But what with the moment of mistake?

Comment: @VirtualUser I added the analysis.

Comment: Ahh, there is mistake but  in calculating. It is not good but still better than mistake in understanding the problem. Anyway, thanks for tip and  analysis